# How to replace the last instance of a substring within a quoted expression

Tags: replace, clojure

Say I have some quoted expression

`'(b (a (c 1 3) 2))`

where I would like to replace the last parenthesis with some value,

`'(b (a (c 1 3) 2) e)`

What is the best way to do this? should I first convert it to a string then flip it, then apply replace-first then flip it back? or is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: just for fun: `\`(~@data ~'e)` => `(b (a (c 1 3) 2) e)`

Comment: You do not “replace a parenthesis”.  That parenthesis is just a printed representation of the end of a list.  You want to append something to a list.

Answer (score 5):

```
user=> (concat '(b (a (c 1 3) 2)) '(e))
(b (a (c 1 3) 2) e)
```